# ADFS 3.0 IdP Initiated Signon for SaaS provider

Tags: saml, wif, adfs, adfs3.0

Custom SaaS Application that has multitenant users. Need to authenticate users into sass application that is protected by ADFS 3.0 do not want to have homerelm discovery. Not sure if this should be a smart link or not? How do I create an authentication flow that has the user click a link that only accepts them if already authenticated from IdP?

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple options based on the SaaS app.

1. If the SaaS app uses SAML protocol, you can use the IPP initiated sign-on in ADFS.
2. If the SaaS app uses WS-Fed, then you can mimic a request and then make it a smartlink where you start the request @ADFS and then flow it through.

The first option is typically preferred.